# How to exclude specific control from css?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, telerik, css-selectors

I have a [telerik treeview](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx?#qsf-demo-source) which renders in HTML as `ul`.

When I try it in my aspx with specific `css`, it doesn't appear in the correct way because the CSS file has `ul` and `li` selectors .

From firebug :

[image]
[image]

---

Now i want to exclude this control from `(#tabContaier ul ,#tabContaier Li)`

I want some general solution to this problem especially with the `telerik` controls.

---

Edit:

After apply the cascade technique :

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server" CheckBoxes="True" Height="200px"
                                                                TriStateCheckBoxes="true"  CheckChildNodes="true" Skin="rad_rv"  EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" >
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to override rules in CSS if you can't change the `.css` file in which these rules are specified.

1. **Cascade**: As the name implies, in CSS rules written later override rules written earlier, whether they are in the same sheet or not.
2. **Specificity**: Be more specific than the rule you want to override with your selectors. [More about specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity).
3. **Inline styles**: Write your styles inside the HTML element using the attribute `style`. This is strongly not recommended, as you should separate presentation and content (that's the whole point of CSS); however, this is the usual way things are done when you override them in javascript (see below). *Inline styles* are really just a particular case (the strongest) of specificity; it's like saying: *“I mean **exactly** this element **here**”*.
4. **Use `!important`** after a rule: resort to this as a last means of overriding, as `!important` overrides anything but user-defined `!important` marked stylesheets.

Of course, since you tagged your question with jQuery, you could do that with jQuery and javascript in general as well. But I don't see, in this case, why you would want to do that.

### Examples

In your case, example of better **cascading** would be just: define `#tabContainer ul` after your telerik stylesheet defines them. Simple as that. When do you import that stylesheet? Move it above your own stylesheet and you will be sure everything you will write will override what's written there.

An example of **specificity**, would be defining something like `#container #tabContainer ul`. This will override the less specific `#tabContainer ul` rule.

**Inline style** would mean that you actually put the styles hard-coded in your element, like so:

```
<ul class=rtUL rtLines" style="height: 40px;">
```

**Using `!important`** works on single rules you want to brute force in, like so:

```
#tabContainer ul {
    height: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot .. The main problem here is :the telerik controls have a special case , they use skin files so i can't access them ,in addition to that i write the renderining result but the control it self is written in .aspx in a specific way .u can take a look on the link example to get what i mean exactly .

Comment: @just_name I am not familiar with telerik, but what I see is this: in the example code there there is a part (inside the `<head>` tag just below the `<title>`) in which you would be able to define your **styles**. On the rendered page example, I see that those styles are rendered before the imported stylesheet. I don't know if this is by design (it would be a bad design) or you could change that. If you could put your own styles **after** the imported styles, you could then use **cascading** (option 1). If you can't, no worries, just use **specificity** (option 2).

Comment: let's remark that steps 3 and 4 are generally considered as bad practice, so try sticking to cascading css and increased specificity

Comment: @Luca My answer clearly state that point 3 is **strongly not recommended** and point 4 should be the **last option**. Bear in mind, though, that there are absolutely legitimate cases in which you would want to use those options; if there wouldn't they wouldn't be in the spec. The problem is **abuse**. Let's just say that you'd better know what you are doing before using 3 or 4.

Comment: I will be grateful if you explain how can i apply the `cascade` technique in my case with more details

Comment: The cascading technique works as follow: *any rule your write later which has **the same specificity** overrides any rule written earlier*. This means: just write your rules **after** the telerik styles in the document head: really simple as that.

Comment: I update my question , i did these instructions but still the old one override the new one !!

Comment: Please elaborate more: what are you showing in that screenshot? I can see that there is an empty set of rules for `#tabcontainer ul` before a full set of rules for the same element. What did you change there? If the empty set of rules is the one you added, why you didn't add any rule there?