# multiple css documents, list style problems

Tags: css, list, styles

My website has two different css style documents. The first is specifically for the index page, which uses lists to do the tabs at the top for a link bar between the title and the rest of it. This has the code:

**index.css**:

```
u1 
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

along with some code which applies to the li elements.

The other css document is for the rest of the site. I want to use lists for some of the other parts, but I'm having an issue. While the li elements are overwriting properly, I can't get u1 element to show the bullets in the rest of the site. I've tried using u1.a and u1.b , but that doesn't fix it.

**main.css**:

```
u1
{
    list-style-type:circle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overwriting it by adding `!important`

```
u1
{
    list-style-type:circle!important;
}
```

and/or add another CSS file with just this rule to the page you want to be different.

Answer (score 0):

The element is `ul` as in `UL` not `u1` and in `u-one`. I assume this is not a typo of the code because it's all over the place in your question.

CSS work by cascading and specificity. Having list style apply to other elements of your site might be as simple as adding a class:

```
ul.circle {
     list-style-type: circle;
}
```

and then adding the same class to your element in the HTML document, as such:

```
<ul class="circle"></ul>
```

There are many different ways to override CSS, and I described them in an [**answer of sometime ago**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268571/how-to-exclude-specific-control-from-css/15268786#15268786), but in your case this should be the easiest.

Comment: thank you for the correction, but using the classes this way did not help.

Comment: It is very unlikely that this did not help. Even less unlikely that adding `!important` did not help either. Perhaps seeing your HTML or live site, it could be possible to solve your problem.

Comment: Look at [this demo of simple HTML and CSS](http://jsbin.com/utexex/1/edit) for what you described.

Comment: I took out using the list for my tabs at the top, and took all ul stuff out of my css to put lists back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to probably reiterate what was already said, but if you wanted to make your 'u-one' class, you should prepend a dot to it, so it is either a class:

```
.u1 {list-style-type: circle;}
```

And you will use it as a usual class, ie

```
<ul class="u1"> <li></li> </ul>
```

or use ul [UL] as a tag:

```
ul {list-style-type: circle;}
```

and all your UL lists will have this formatting.

The way you put it in your css will not work with html because the 'u1' tag does not exist.
But I'll need to see a snippet of your html to be sure.